# XDocument attribute of existing node does not exist

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm pulling in an XML set from a web service, loading it into XDocument and then parsing it out.  On one node, the attribute, which is CLEARLY there if I output the XML to a file, is telling me that it doesn't exist.  And I cannot figure out what stupid thing I'm doing to cause this error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MESSAGE xmlns="http://www.mismo.org/residential/2009/schemas_v1_4_2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<DEAL_SETS>
    <DEAL_SET>
        <DEALS>
            <DEAL>
                <ASSETS>
                    <OWNED_PROPERTIES>
                        <OWNED_PROPERTY SequenceNumber="1">
                            <OWNED_PROPERTY_DETAIL>
                                <PropertyUsageType>PrimaryResidence</PropertyUsageType>
                            </OWNED_PROPERTY_DETAIL>
                        </OWNED_PROPERTY>
                        <OWNED_PROPERTY SequenceNumber="2">
                            <OWNED_PROPERTY_DETAIL>
                                <PropertyUsageType>PrimaryResidence</PropertyUsageType>
                            </OWNED_PROPERTY_DETAIL>
                        </OWNED_PROPERTY>
                    </OWNED_PROPERTIES>
                </ASSETS>
                <COLLATERALS>
                    <COLLATERAL SequenceNumber="1">
                        <COLLATERAL_DETAIL>
                            <LienPriorityExceptionType>FirstLien</LienPriorityExceptionType>
                        </COLLATERAL_DETAIL>
                        <PROPERTIES>
                            <PROPERTY>
                                <FLOOD_DETERMINATION>
                                    <FLOOD_DETERMINATION_DETAIL/>
                                </FLOOD_DETERMINATION>
                                <IMPROVEMENT>
                                    <UNIT_GROUPS>
                                        <UNIT_GROUP>
                                            <UNIT_GROUP_DETAIL>
                                                <UnitType>UnitOne</UnitType>
                                            </UNIT_GROUP_DETAIL>
                                            <ROOM_TYPE_SUMMARY/>
                                        </UNIT_GROUP>
                                    </UNIT_GROUPS>
                                </IMPROVEMENT>
                            </PROPERTY>
                        </PROPERTIES>
                    </COLLATERAL>
                    <COLLATERAL SequenceNumber="5">
                        <COLLATERAL_DETAIL>
                            <LienPriorityExceptionType>FirstLien</LienPriorityExceptionType>
                        </COLLATERAL_DETAIL>
                        <PROPERTIES>
                            <PROPERTY>
                                <FLOOD_DETERMINATION>
                                    <FLOOD_DETERMINATION_DETAIL/>
                                </FLOOD_DETERMINATION>
                                <IMPROVEMENT>
                                    <UNIT_GROUPS>
                                        <UNIT_GROUP>
                                            <UNIT_GROUP_DETAIL>
                                                <UnitType>UnitOne</UnitType>
                                            </UNIT_GROUP_DETAIL>
                                            <ROOM_TYPE_SUMMARY/>
                                        </UNIT_GROUP>
                                    </UNIT_GROUPS>
                                </IMPROVEMENT>
                            </PROPERTY>
                        </PROPERTIES>
                    </COLLATERAL>
                </COLLATERALS>
             </DEAL>
           </DEALS>
        </DEAL_SET>
     </DEAL_SETS>
  </MESSAGE>
```

My code can find the SequenceNumber value of OWNED_PROPERTY just fine, but blows up on COLLATERAL:

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Collections.Generic;

XDocument resx = new XDocument();

public override void MethodInternal()
{
  string uid = "something";
  string pwd = "somethingelse";
  string httppath = "url";

  try
  {
    NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential(uid, pwd);
    CredentialCache credCache = new CredentialCache();
    credCache.Add(new Uri(httppath), "NTLM", cred);
    WebRequest client = WebRequest.Create(httppath);

    client.Credentials = credCache;
    client.Method = "GET";
    client.ContentType = "application/xml";

    WebResponse resp = client.GetResponse();
    Stream respStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader strrdr = new StreamReader(respStream);
    string allxml = strrdr.ReadToEnd();

    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fullstr);

    XNamespace ns = "http://www.mismo.org/residential/2009/schemas_v1_4_2";
    resx = XDocument.Parse(allxml);
    strrdr.Close();
    respStream.Close();
    resp.Close();

    int seqnum = 0;
    int cseqnum = 0;

        foreach (XElement b in resx.Root.Descendants(ns + "DEAL"))
        {
            // Primary node: ASSETS
            if (b.Elements(ns + "ASSETS").Any())
            {
                IEnumerable<XElement> axl = b.Descendants(ns + "ASSETS");
                foreach (var axcol in axl.Elements())
                {
                    seqnum = 0;
                    IEnumerable<XElement> opxl = b.Descendants(ns + "OWNED_PROPERTY");
                    foreach (var opxlcol in axl.Elements())
                    {
                        seqnum = int.Parse(opxlcol.Element(ns + "OWNED_PROPERTY").Attribute("SequenceNumber").Value.ToString());

                        IEnumerable<XElement> opxls = opxlcol.Descendants(ns + "OWNED_PROPERTY");
                        foreach (var opxlsc in opxls.Elements())
                        {
                            if (opxlsc.Elements(ns + "PropertyUsageType").Any())
                                //occa.Add(seqnum, opxlsc.Element(ns + "PropertyUsageType").Value.ToString());
                        }
                    } // OWNED_PROPERTY XElements 
                } // XElements under ASSETS
            } // test to make sure ASSETS exists

            // Primary node: COLLATERALS
            if (b.Elements(ns + "COLLATERALS").Any())
            {
                IEnumerable<XElement> colsxl = b.Descendants(ns + "COLLATERALS");
                foreach (var clsxl in colsxl.Elements())
                {
                    cseqnum = 0;
                    IEnumerable<XElement> clxl = clsxl.DescendantsAndSelf(ns + "COLLATERAL");
                    foreach (var clxll in clxl.Elements())
                    {
                        //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ns.ToString() + clsxl.Name.LocalName.ToString());
                        //if (clsxl.Name.LocalName.ToString() == "COLLATERAL")
                        //{
                        bool bv = resx.Descendants("COLLATERAL").Select(x => (int?)x.Attribute("SequenceNumber")).FirstOrDefault(x => x != null) > 0;
                            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(bv.ToString());
                            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(clsxl.Element(ns + "COLLATERAL").Attribute("SequenceNumber").Value.ToString());
                            cseqnum = int.Parse(clsxl.Element(ns + "COLLATERAL").Attribute("SequenceNumber").Value.ToString());
                        //}

                        if (clxll.Elements(ns + "LienPropertyExceptionType").Any())
                            //liena.Add(cseqnum, clxll.Element(ns + "LienPropertyExceptionType").Value.ToString());

                        IEnumerable<XElement> pxl = clsxl.Descendants(ns + "PROPERTY");
                        foreach (var p in pxl.Elements())
                        {
                            if (p.Elements(ns + "IMPROVEMENT").Any())
                            {
                                IEnumerable<XElement> ig = p.Descendants(ns + "IMPROVEMENT");
                                foreach (var igxl in ig.Elements())
                                {
                                    if (igxl.Elements(ns + "UnitType").Any())
                                        //nua.Add(cseqnum, igxl.Element(ns + "UnitType").Value.ToString());
                                    //} // XElements under UNIT_GROUP_DETAIL
                                } // XElements under IMPROVEMENT
                            } // test to make sure IMPROVEMENT exists
                        } // XElements under PROPERTY
                    }  // XElements in COLLATERAL
                }  // XElements under COLLATERALS
            } // test to make sure COLLATERALS exists
         } // root
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    //handle exception
  }
}
```

So where am I going wrong?  The only diffs other than textual in the XML are that the OWNED_PROPERTY tag is under an additional  tag, while  is directly beneath . But as you can see my code is skipping past the  tag, as it's useless for my purposes.

Comment: You use namespaces in your code, but your sample doesn't use any of them; probably will be easier to spot the problem with a more real example.

Comment: also you seem to not understand that `.Descendants()` will search the whole tree under the node, not just the next element.  Most of your code is very unneccessary

Comment: `fxl` should be a collection of all the "element2" elements, but then you call `Elements` on that in your foreach, basically getting all the children of the "element2" elements into `elfx`, then you call `Element` on that looking for a "element2".  I don't see how your code would work with the example at all.

Comment: None of your parsing code works on the XML you provide.

Comment: Even if I set `ns = ""`, `resx.Root.Descendants(ns + "Root")` returns no elements, since `<root>` *is* the root element (and in any event is named `root` not `Root`.)  To help you we need a [mcve] that actually executes a line of code that unsuccessfully tries to access an attribute.

Comment: Sorry y'all.  I updated the question with real XML and real code.  Was trying to spare you and I went off in COMPLETELY the wrong direction. :)

Comment: "My code can find the idnum value of element1 just fine, but blows up on element2:" - the code doesn't assign to `idnum` **at all**, in any code path... seriously, `idnum` only comes up twice: once in the declaration (`int idnum = 0;`), and once in the phrase I quoted.

Comment: Your new code doesn't compile -- `seqnum` and `cseqnum` are undefined, as are `occa` and `rvx` and `liena` and `nua`.

Comment: If you like, just comment out the occa/liena/nua references; they're dictionary objects and not relevant for this code.  Fixing rvx now.

Comment: OP, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so your variable names are `clsxl`, `clxll`, `clxl`, `chicxulub`, `mxyzptlk`, and `lerxst`. Sensible enough.

This line threw an exception. Somewhere lost in the depths of that expression, something's returning null. Well, you can't debug that by pasting the whole thing in between the parens of a call to `MessageBox.Show()`, because the whole point is it throws an exception instead of returning a value.

```
//System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(clsxl.Element(ns + "COLLATERAL").Attribute("SequenceNumber").Value.ToString());
cseqnum = int.Parse(clsxl.Element(ns + "COLLATERAL").Attribute("SequenceNumber").Value.ToString());
```

Here's what you do: Break it down into the simplest possible expressions and see what returns what. Takes a while, but so does reading all those comments from people moaning about variable declarations.

```
var element = clsxl.Element(ns + "COLLATERAL");

var attr = element.Attribute("SequenceNumber");

//  attr.Value is already a string. If it's anything. 
cseqnum = int.Parse(attr.Value);
```

Set a breakpoint on the first of those lines, and hover the mouse over everything as you go.

What you'll find is that `clsxl` is "COLLATERAL". It has no child named "COLLATERAL" with a "SequenceNumber" attribute. *It* has the "SequenceNumber" attribute.

```
//  Ain't no such animal
var element = clsxl.Element(ns + "COLLATERAL");
```

`clsxl` is the parent loop variable. That's "COLLATERAL". That's the one you want.

```
var attr = clsxl.Attribute("SequenceNumber");
cseqnum = int.Parse(attr.Value);
```

I have a gut feeling you could lose 50% of this code and sleep easier, but I didn't try to tease out the intent of every little bit, so that could be a high estimate.

In all seriousness, I do understand where you're getting those names from. They're not noise, they're based on the XML element names. However, I would be calling them `xnCollateral` and so on. The extra typing pays for itself. Those very compact '70s C style identifiers were a reasonable compromise when we had 80x25 characters on a VT100, but we've all got much bigger screens now.

Comment: Thank you a zillion!  I followed your hints and restructured the code and now it's happier.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML document have a default namespace, so all navigation operations must use it. You done right in most places, but you're missing the namespace in lines like:

```
bool bv = resx.Descendants("COLLATERAL")
```